# How to get this only in small letters (lowercase)?

Tags: categories

I used the following code to give out the category name (without link) in a single post.

How would it be possible for the category name that is given out to only appears in small letters ?

I just think this has to be made with substring, but I dont get it :)
Could somebody please help me :)

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?>
```

Comment: There is the PHP function `strtolower`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally achieve this by using `strtolower` which changes the case of the string.

```
<?php 
    $categories = get_the_category();

    foreach($categories as $category)
    { 
        echo strtolower($category->cat_name) . ' ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: My pleasure Rodney.